# Module not found error can't resolve angular 7

Tags: angular

I am trying to integrate interactive d3 bubble chart with angular 7 but when building my sample application I always get

```
module not found error can't resolve 'd3' in '.../Angular_Example/angular-d3-graph-example-master/src/app/d3'
```

Please help me, Thanks

```
import { Node, Link, ForceDirectedGraph } from './models';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Injectable()
export class D3Service {
  constructor() { }


  applyZoomableBehaviour(svgElement, containerElement) {
    let svg, container, zoomed, zoom;

    svg = d3.select(svgElement);
    container = d3.select(containerElement);

    zoomed = () => {

  }

  applyDraggableBehaviour(element, node: Node, graph: ForceDirectedGraph) {

    }


  }


  getForceDirectedGraph(nodes: Node[], links: Link[], options: { width, height }) {
    const sg = new ForceDirectedGraph(nodes, links, options);
    return sg;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed the module with `npm install -d d3` ?

Comment: yes, Install d3 library using command npm install d3 --save and then Install d3 library types using command npm install @types/d3 --save

Comment: @mayuringole for me this fixed the issue :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Taking into account feedback of @mayuringole here are the steps:

```
npm install d3 --save
npm install @types/d3 --save
```

This fixed the issue for me. In my case I tried to use the d3 lib via the `<script>` tag and not all components were recognized

By installing the modules via npm  + `import * as d3 from "d3";` it went ok